# Cannot persist NoScript settings on TorBrowser 8

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, linux, noscript

NoScript resetting to default after closing Tor Browser

NoScript default is enabling script, object, media, frame, font, webgl, fetch, other!!

I can manually go to extension page and reset to true default settings which is frame, fetch, other.

When close and open Tor Browser, NoScript defaults back to script, object, media, frame, font, webgl, fetch, other!!

How to have NoScript save settings between launch of Tor Browser?

Some other info:

- upgraded from 7.x to 8.0.1
- using linux

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/27175

Looks like the fix will be released very soon with the next update.

Answer (score 2):

Since [NoScript 10.2.2](https://noscript.net/changelog#10.2.2) you can check *NoScript Options>Advanced>**Override Tor Browser's Security Level preset***.
Also Notice that in Tor Browser 9 NoScript's and HTTPS Everywere's toolbar buttons are hidden in order to further emphasize the Security Level UI: if you need to fine tune the underlying extensions you'll probably want to bring those buttons back from the *Customize* menu item.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the *Tor Browser Security Settings* **Security Level** to `Safest`, which only enables `frame` and `other` by default.

Unfortunately, as of Tor Browser 8.0.4, it looks like I can't save per-site permissions across sessions, even with [the new `extensions.torbutton.noscript_persist` setting](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/27175#comment:13).